# On their own account

Tags: meaning

I’m reading Rudyard Kipling’s Kim, where in Ch 6 it says:

> Men of other régiments came to visit the Mavericks. The Mavericks went visiting *on their own account*.

What does it mean, *on their own account*? My understanding of *account* is either “report, description “, or something like a “bank account “, but seems neither works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On one's own account" is an idiom and it means for one's own purpose.

*[Collinsdictionary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-ones-own-account)*

> - If you do something **on** your **own account**, you do it because you want to and without being asked, and you take responsibility for your own action.
> - If you take part in a business activity **on** your **own account**, you do    it for yourself, and not as a representative or employee of a company.

[*TheFreeDictionary:*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+own+account)

> Without requiring or having been given instruction, prompting, or
>   guidance from others; by one's own effort or energy.